# CF: Setup DLL (template missing)

Tags: c#, compact-framework, setup-project

Im trying to create setup for my cf app.

I cant seem to find the project template "Win32 Smart Device DLL" under visual c++.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found it. Its the Win32 Smart Device Project template and inside there is a DLL option.